# What does the appearance of a Ten Ring terrorist in Ant-Man mean?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, ant-man, ant-man-2015

In *Ant-Man*, we can see at one point that one of the potential buyers for the Yellowjacket (Darren Cross' version of the Ant-Man technology) has a tattoo on his neck. Under closer inspection, it becomes obvious that this tattoo is the logo for the Ten Ring terrorists.

Below is a picture of the character in question, and the logo for the Ten Ring terrorists for comparison (you may need to zoom in on the guys neck).

[image: Ten Ring man 2]
[image: Ten Ring logo]

There are other pictures online that show the tattoo too - the one where the tattoo is most visible comes from a deleted scene.

Has anyone involved with either *Ant-Man* or the larger Marvel Cinematic Universe commented on this? I'd be interested to know what link, if any, this has to *Iron Man 3* or the "All Hail the King" One-Shot.

Comment: Interesting catch! I feel like it's just to add continuity, but I hope we get a strong answer.

Comment: 10ring., possible (true) mandarin reference?

Comment: Ten Rings has been around from the very beginning (Iron Man 2008): http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-KIyKPD-H4_4/UZBUOvSB2CI/AAAAAAAAYj8/a_ebn85aIjU/s1600/Ten+Rings+2.jpg

Answer (score 8):

For what we know now, it's that it could be a foreshadowing of the phase 4 of the MCU with *Shang-Chi and the Legend of the Ten Rings* as it has been announced few days ago.

Marvel like to give hints of what will happen in next movies of the MCU, but discretly enough in case nothing will go out as expected.

Answer (score 4):

Most likely just for an easter egg/cameo. Darren Cross was portrayed as insane and corrupt. It is extremely in-character for a guy like him to sell super-weapons to terrorist organizations. As of this point, there really is no official explanation.